# Identify new items in list compared to multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying find a better way to identify new items in a list (Current Month sheet) by comparing items from multiple sheets (6 Sheets).

Below is the current formula which is working <strike>but if a row gets added/deleted in any sheet the formula breaks since the sheets are no longer the same length</strike>.

Here is a sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zb5_d_gUz8iu963AyXosVufCm6NmBs8pcaEzVAXAmIY/edit?usp=sharing

```
=ArrayFormula(FILTER('Current Month'!A2:K,
NOT(COUNTIFS('D&C'!N2:N,'Current Month'!K2:K,'D&C'!J2:J,'Current Month'!G2:G)),
NOT(COUNTIFS(Leasing!N2:N,'Current Month'!K2:K,Leasing!J2:J,'Current Month'!G2:G)),
NOT(COUNTIFS('Facilities Management'!N2:N,'Current Month'!K2:K,'Facilities Management'!J2:J,'Current Month'!G2:G)),
NOT(COUNTIFS('Project Delivery'!N2:N,'Current Month'!K2:K,'Project Delivery'!J2:J,'Current Month'!G2:G)),
NOT(COUNTIFS('Service Center'!N2:N,'Current Month'!K2:K,'Service Center'!J2:J,'Current Month'!G2:G))))
```

Comment: can you share an editable sample sheet so that ideas can be tested and demonstrated?

Comment: Give me a minute to build one on my personal account since I can't share anything from my work account.

Comment: @MattKing As I was making the sample sheet I realized that all I needed to do was add NOT(COUNTIFS for each sheet and that will get rid of the add/delete issue. I've update my question with a link to a sample sheet but I am still looking to see if there is a better way to do that.